# ViewExpiredException shown in java.lang.Throwable error-page in web.xml

Tags: jsf, servlets, web.xml, custom-error-pages, viewexpiredexception

I'm working on a JSF web application in which I need to bring up a "Session Expired" page if the view expires, but a general technical error page for all others.  The application only goes to the technical error page when I trigger the exception.  Here's the error-page definitions:

```
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type> 
    <location>/jsps/utility/sessionExpired.jsp</location> 
</error-page> 
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/jsps/utility/technicalError.jsp</location> 
</error-page> 
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/jsps/utility/technicalError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I removed the technicalError.jsp error page elements and it worked fine, but when I put them back I can't get to the sessionExpired.jsp page.  How do I tell the web container the order to evaluate these tags so that the right page comes up?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

This is because the [`ViewExpiredException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewExpiredException.html) is been wrapped in a [`ServletException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html) as per the JSF specification. Here's an extract of chapter 10.2.6.2 of the [JSF 1.2 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr252/index2.html):

> #### 10.2.6.2 FacesServlet
>
> Call the `execute()` method of the saved `Lifecycle` instance, passing the
>   `FacesContext` instance for this request as a parameter. If the `execute()` method
>   throws a `FacesException`, **re-throw it as a `ServletException` with the
>   `FacesException` as the root cause**.

How the error pages are allocated is specified in Servlet API specification. Here's an extract of chapter 9.9.2 of [Servlet API specification 2.5](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index2.html):

> #### SRV.9.9.2 Error Pages
>
> If **no** `error-page` declaration containing an `exception-type` fits using the
>   **class-hierarchy match**, and the exception thrown is a `ServletException` or
>   subclass thereof, the container extracts the wrapped exception, as defined by
>   the `ServletException.getRootCause` method. **A second pass** is made over the error
>   page declarations, again attempting the match against the error page
>   declarations, but using the wrapped exception instead.

In class hierarchy, `ServletException` already matches `Throwable`, so its root cause won't be extracted for the second pass.

To prove this specified behaviour, replace `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException` by `javax.servlet.ServletException` as `<exception-type>` and retry. You'll see the expected error page being displayed.

To solve this, simply **remove** the error page on `java.lang.Throwable` or `java.lang.Exception`. If no one exception specific error page matches, then it will fall back to the one for error code of `500` anyway. So, all you need is this:

```
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type> 
    <location>/jsps/utility/sessionExpired.jsp</location> 
</error-page> 
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/jsps/utility/technicalError.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

---

**Update**: as per the (deleted) comment of the OP: to reliably test this you cannot do a `throw new ViewExpiredException()` in a bean constructor or method or so. It would in turn get wrapped in some EL exception. You can eventually add a debug line printing `rootCause` in the `Filter` to see it yourself.

If you're using Eclipse/Tomcat, a quick way to test `ViewExpiredException` is the following:

1. Create a JSF page with a simple command button, deploy and run it and open it in webbrowser.
2. Go back to Eclipse, rightclick Tomcat server and choose *Clean Tomcat Work Directory*. This will restart Tomcat **and** trash all serialized sessions (important! just restarting Tomcat is not enough).
3. Go back to webbrowser and press the command button (without reloading page beforehand!).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, the solution does not work. The technical error pages comes up instead of session expired page.  I terminated the session by restarting the application in the middle of a session.  

I found that I can do a response.sendRedirect in that try block instead of throwing a runtime exception, but then I'm hard-coding a path to a view instead of letting the container control it.  Not preferred, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: This works fine here on Tomcat 6.0.20. What servletcontainer are you using? What rootCause are you getting?

Comment: I didn't mention that I cannot remove the <error-page> block for the error code 500.  It's part of a coding standard in my shop.

Comment: Websphere Application Server v6.1.

Comment: I'm getting the expected root cause, ViewExpiredException. It seems like everything *should* be working, but the container is just not "prioritizing" the errors correctly.

Comment: I really appreciate your help so far; it's been a privilege to learn from such a knowledgeable person.

Comment: Websphere, sorry, I don't have that running here right now. I did another test in Glassfish to be sure and it works there as well. Seems to be a Websphere specific issue now .. Try upgrading .. What's the behaviour when you replace `ViewExpiredException` in `<exception-type>` by `ServletException`?

Comment: I would just get the technical error page. I've decided to forego letting the container handle it and just do a redirect. Since the issue is WebSphere specific and I'm forced to use it, that's the best I'm going to do.

Comment: For those in my position looking for more information on implementing BalusC's filter suggestion, this was quite useful: http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/

Comment: @Mark: see also the `[servlet-filters]` tag info page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: This solution is great, but for runtime exceptions only. What about checked exceptions? They still are falling back to ServletException match...

Comment: @PavelS: use OmniFaces `FacesExceptionFilter` instead: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your reply! I am already using the OmniFaces filter. It does only part of the job unwrapping from FacesException my custom checked exception. Since the above solution makes no effect, a `ServletException` with my checked exception as its cause is coming to error page matchings where `Throwable` or `Exception` fallback picks up the `ServletException` itself, not concrete checked exception. My current solution is just to not use fallback declaration at all, having error page declarations for all possible concrete exceptions including checked ones...

Comment: @PavelS: oh, that way. Just remove `java.lang.Throwable`/`java.lang.Exception` and keep `500` in as general fallback for other exceptions. See also the answer.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you so much, having a `500` way went away from my mind. So, OmniFaces filter + no error page declarations for global exceptions + `500` general fallback is a nice way to go for me.

Comment: @BalusC: Since ViewExpiredException has been wrapped in a ServletException and as there was no error-page declaration for ServletException in web.xml file for OP question, the container is going extract the wrapped exception(i.e ViewExpiredException ), by using the ServletException.getRootCause(). Why the  root cause won't be extracted for the second pass? I am unable to understand this line of yours -[....In class hierarchy, ServletException already matches Throwable, so its root cause won't be extracted for the second pass....]

Comment: @Shirgill: ServletException is an instance of Throwable.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes I know it very well, The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language. Request you to please elaborate on that line which I mentioned.Why the root cause won't be extracted for the second pass?

Comment: @Shirgill: Because there's already a match on first pass. There's (incorrectly) an error page configured for java.lang.Throwable and ServletException is an instance of Throwable.

Comment: @BalusC: Since Throwable sits on the top of the exception & errors hierarrchy, can you give me an example when there will not be  match on first pass.

Comment: @Shirgill: as answered, replace it by `<error-code>500`.

Comment: @BalusC: But if I recall it correctly, then in the stacktrace sometimes, I have seen ...javax.servlet.ServletException: ... for servlet .... for HTTP 500. Or am I completely wrong to assume that HTTP 500 is mapped/corresponds to ServletException in ServletAPI? I think this is the root cause which is confusing me.

Comment: @Shirgill: HTTP 500 is just an [error code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). In Java terms, it basically means "an uncaught exception has occurred on server side". The `<exception-type>` allows fine grained error page matching to exception types. If no one matches in the end, then error page associated with `<error-code>` 500 will be used, if any.

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you very much for elucidating it to the deep extent.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by BylusC, deployment descriptor must not contain any error-page handler that will catch ViewExpiredException (wrapped inside ServletException) instead of the correct one - error-page for ViewExpiredException.

Do not forget to verify that server's deployment descriptor (e.g. TomEE/conf/web.xml) does not contain  java.lang.Throwable or java.lang.Exception error-page definitions. Because these two web.xml are basically merged.

Yes - application's web.xml has precedence over server's web.xml, but if application's web.xml contains

- error-page for 500 (/error.xhtml)

and server's web.xml for

- 500 (/500.html) and for
- Throwable (/bigerror.html)

then application context will contain merge of those two:

- 500 (/error.xhtml)
- Throwable (/bigerror.html)

and ViewExpiredExcpetion error handling will not work correctly.