# How can I set the view timeout?

Tags: session, jsf-2, view, timeout

In our **JSF2** project on JBoss 7.1.1, we define a session timeout in the `web.xml` and it works just fine.

However, sometimes we're getting view expiration, leading to errors like this one even if the session is still alive:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/... - View /... could 
not be restored.
```

Where can we **set the view timeout**, like we did for sessions? Or is the view expiration caused by something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another cause of `ViewExpiredException` is that *too many* logical views are been created in the session. The default limit is JSF implementation specific and every synchronous GET request on a particular view basically creates a new view. So, for example, when you use Mojarra (which has a default limit of 15) and start a browser session and open the same view in 16 different tabs and then submit a form in the 1st one, then you may get this exception as well. The limit is configureable with a JSF implementation specific context parameter, which is [`com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews`](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/JavaServerFacesRI#JavaServerFacesRI-Whatcontextparametersareavailableandwhatdotheydo?) for Mojarra and [`org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION`](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Performance) in MyFaces (defaults to 20).

This is however a very rare real world problem. If your webapp is really designed to be used this way (e.g. a social/community site which invites to being opened in multiple tabs, such as discussion forum or Q&A), then you might consider using client side state saving instead.

#### See also:

- [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969)
- [com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession vs com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105439/com-sun-faces-numberofviewsinsession-vs-com-sun-faces-numberoflogicalviews/16050424#16050424)

Comment: Hm, seems good, thanks. But anyway, is there a view expiration timeout and if there is, how is its lifespan defined?

Comment: There's no timeout other than the session timeout. There's as answered however the "maximum views" setting which you could set higher up. A view is created when you request a view for the first time by a GET request and lives as long as you postbacks to it while not navigating to a different view (as in ajax postbacks and return null/void actions).