# Enforce javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException for testing application

Tags: java, jsf, viewexpiredexception

I would like to test my webapplication (JSF 2.2) which has a custom Esxception Handler Factory.
Now i would like to know if everything works as expected when a javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException is thrown. Is there any way, I can decrease the time to wait for getting this exception?
Throwing it programmatically is not an option, as I would like to have a nearly 100% productive test scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, it should be enough to **force a Session expiration** while you keep the JSF view state in the server side:

> Setting STATE_SAVING_METHOD to client has however an additional functional advantage: it prevents ViewExpiredExceptions when the session has expired or when the client opens too many views.

So, being the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` defaulted to `server`, you only need to specify the timeout you want for the Http Session:

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

**As an alternative**, you could choose to **set your own limit of views**. That depends on the concrete JSF implementation, Mojarra defaults to 16 and MyFaces to 20. For the first one, you could use `com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews` to decrease the amount of views accepted simultaneously per client. As an example, setting it to 3 should fire the exception when you've got four tabs opened in the same browser (same Http Session).

**See also:**

- [What is STATE_SAVING_METHOD parameter in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471551/what-is-state-saving-method-parameter-in-jsf-2-0)
- [Session TimeOut in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382895/session-timeout-in-web-xml)
- [How can I set the view timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562469/how-can-i-set-the-view-timeout)

Answer (score 2):

In Google Chrome you can use the Developer Tools to delete the session cookie.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Web.xml

you should have something like:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
      30
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

Where the timeout is in minutes, so set to 1