# jsf view expired imply session destroyed?

Tags: jsf, session, viewexpiredexception

I have a question :

When jsf view has expired, can we be sure that the session is destroyed and all its attributes are removed ?

Thank you for responding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's the other way round, provided that `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is set to its default value of `server`. Then a session destroy indeed implies an expireation of all views saved so far in the session. If the state saving is however set to `client`, then the view never expires.

#### See also:

- [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969)
- [com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession vs com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105439/com-sun-faces-numberofviewsinsession-vs-com-sun-faces-numberoflogicalviews/16050424#16050424)