# Leaving <p:dialog><p:tabView> open for a long time causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source at java.util.EventObject.<init>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using default Mojarra that comes with Glassfish open source edition 3.1.2.2 (version 2.1.6 I think). I have a `<p:dialog>` with a `<p:tabView>` and each tab has some buttons/links in it. When I open the dialog and do some ajax operations by button/link click everything works fine. If I open the dialog box and leave it for some time (say 10 mins), then I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:38)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.<init>(SystemEvent.java:67)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.<init>(ComponentSystemEvent.java:69)
```

I tried [OmniFaces restorable view](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/enableRestorableView). The exception doesn't occur anymore, but the dialog closes and nothing happens, the listeners in the bean are not triggered.

In my `web.xml`, I have specified a very high session timeout (in hours). I suppose it is not the view expired due to session timeout. The [number of logical views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105439/com-sun-faces-numberofviewsinsession-vs-com-sun-faces-numberoflogicalviews/16050424#16050424) is default (which is 15 I suppose). But we are not opening 15 browser tabs in the same session. The issue is occurring even with 1-2 tabs.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: It seems it has more to do with primefaces rather than with JSF. Which PF version are you using? You could try setting up a test project to reproduce the issue with a minimal code, then post the code.

Comment: PF 3.5. I will set up a test project and will post it.