# How JSF identifies the ViewState by id and assigns into view Map

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, myfaces, ibm-jsf

As per my understanding, JSF creates Logical View per new Page and Physical View for different state of the same page on each post back.
JSF creates new ViewState id for each post back on the same page. In our application, we are using JSF 1.2 Sun RI and We have set No of Views in Session = 3. If the ViewState id is new for every post request, 
How JSF will determine the view to restore and replaces the LRU View with the new ViewState ?

For e.g. for 3 post requests it creates 3 Views and put it into 1 Logical Map, will the 4th post request will replace the 1st view in the Map ?
The reason because during the peak load, the data getting lost from the page when we send multiple post back request using IBM JWL Ajax calls. 
Can anyone faced the similar issue and resolved it ?

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105439/com-sun-faces-numberofviewsinsession-vs-com-sun-faces-numberoflogicalviews At least, it should explain how those views are interpreted.

Comment: It's not happening as it was explained, always it returns the new ViewState id for post back and we are able to navigate back button. Anyway The user will not use back button and submit the form,they  submit the same form either by multiple ajax calls and whole form submit. This is working fine when no of users are less and it behaves differently when the users are more.The form data disappears only to the target area(div) from where the ajax call is made and then when we do entire form submit all data in the screen disappears. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to resolve this?