# How to invalidate views for the current session in JSF?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

We have an application (Mojarra 2.3) where a user can change a global filter of the data it sees. When that happens, I want to keep the session, but invalidate the active views (which are server side).

I found this question which enables you to count the number of views: [How do I count the number of views in a user's JSF session (JSF 2.2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344718/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-views-in-a-users-jsf-session-jsf-2-2)

Based on that I figured I could remove the attribute in which the views are stored. I came up with this method:

```java
public static void invalidateViews() {
  final HttpSession session = Faces.getSession();
  List.of("com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewContexts",
          "com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps",
          "com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap",
          "org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations")
          .forEach(session::removeAttribute);
  Faces.redirect(Faces.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString());
}
```

The `com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap` was mentioned in the linked question's answer. I kind of guessed that it would not hurt to remove the other attributes. The answer also mentions that it is Mojarra only.

It seems to work so far, but I would like to ask this: should one clear server side views like this? And, if so, how can I support MyFaces as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to work so far, but I would like to ask this: should one clear server side views like this?

Given that there is no standard API call for this, this is about the best you can do, yes. I have during the JSF 2.3 work requested for a more specific variant of this functionality to exist in the standard API because I needed to be able to destroy view scoped beans associated with a specific JSF view state (for the OmniFaces view scope unload functionality, see [`Hacks#removeViewState()`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/4.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Hacks.java#L271)). But this has unfortunately not yet been fleshed out because of difficulties with Portlets.

> And, if so, how can I support MyFaces as well?

As seen in the OmniFaces [`Hacks`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/4.0/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Hacks.java#L87) helper class, the session attribute key for MyFaces 2.x is [`org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.SERIALIZED_VIEW`](https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/2.3.x/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/application/viewstate/ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java#L59) and 4.x [`org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate.StateCacheServerSide.SERIALIZED_VIEW`](https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/main/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/application/viewstate/StateCacheServerSide.java#L55).

By the way,

> ```java
> Faces.redirect(Faces.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString());
> ```

this is shorter:

```java
Faces.refreshWithQueryString();
```