# How to redirect back to the user desire access page after user login?

Tags: redirect, authentication, jsf-2

Before user login, if type `xxx.detail.jsf`, it will redirect to the login page let user login. This task has been done already. How can I make it to redirect back to the `xxx.detail.jsf` after the user successfull login?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7 and Mojarra 2.0.3.

Comment: What you mean is certainly unclear. What do you mean "*if type `xxx.detail.jsf`, it will redirect to the login page*"?

Comment: @Lion if the user trying to access some page(eg: detail.jsf) before login, the system will redirect the user to the login page, and redirect back to the page(eg: detail.jsf) that the user want to access after the user successful login to the system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the point when you're redirecting to the login page, you need to save the current request URI. You're likely using a `Filter` to perform the login check and the redirect. In that case, you can use `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` to obtain the current request URI:

```
String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
```

You could either pass it as a request parameter in the redirect URL or store it in the session. Passing as a request parameter is the safest:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsf?from=" + URLEncoder.encode(requestURI, "UTF-8"));
```

In the bean associated with the login page, you could set it as a managed property or a view parameter. Let's assume that the bean is view scoped so that you can perform nice ajax actions/validations and like. In that case, the view parameter is the only neat way:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="from" value="#{login.from}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Then, when the real login succeeds, you can redirect to that URI by `ExternalContext#redirect()`:

```
public void login() throws IOException {
    // ...

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(from);
}
```

*(if necessary supply a default target for the case that `from` is `null`)*

Comment: can you please guide me how to add in your answer in my code.
`externalContext.redirect(from);`
I get error on this line

Comment: It's available by the `FacesContext` the usual way. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot.
Can you show me if I want to count down 3sec then only start to redirect back to the page, how to do this?

Comment: Redirect to an intermediate page which has a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=#{bean.from}">` in the `<h:head>`.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick reply.

Comment: BalusC, I refer to here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992526/how-to-handle-session-expiration-in-jsf-2-0?answertab=active#tab-top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992526/how-to-handle-session-expiration-in-jsf-2-0?answertab=active#tab-top)
The below code doesn't work for me, after my session was expired, It won't redirect to the home page, may assist?
`<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/home.xhtml</location>
</error-page>`

Comment: @BalusC The solution above seems to lose the request parameters from the original request. To include the http request parameters from the original page would it just be a matter of iterating through `request.getParameterMap()` and appending the key/value pairs to the `requestURI` string before encoding?

Comment: @Ryan: `request.getQueryString()` is easier.