# define error pages location jsf 2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewexpiredexception

I am trying to redirect my user to the login page when the session expires. I followed the instructions on this link [How to handle session expiration and ViewExpiredException in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992526/how-to-handle-session-expiration-in-jsf-2-0) and it works, except for the fact that it redirects me to a non existing page.

In my application root, I have a login.xhtml page. So in my web.xml I have this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

But while using the application I am at localhost/sample/user/create.sm when the session expires, it redirects me to localhost/sample/user/login.xhtml, while I expected to be redirected to localhost/sample/login.sm. How should I make the correct configuration?

I am using jboss 6.1 and mojarra 2.1.7

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `<location>` has to match the `FacesServlet` mapping. You seem to have mapped it on `*.sm` instead of `*.xhtml`. In that case, change `/login.xhtml` to `/login.sm`.

Comment: I tried that... did not work. I even tried to put /sample/login.xhtml, sample is my context. But it also did not work.

Comment: Well, I don't see any other possible causes based on the information given so far.