# Single entry/exit point design in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I want to design my application in JSF 2.0 with single entry/exit point for all the requests and responses so that they can be routed through a single managedBean/controller.

The purpose of having this design is to catch my all business exceptions at common place and also it would be easy for me to check for the validation of session for each new request.

One of the option I see is ServletFilter but I am not sure if this would be the best approach with JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The purpose of having this design is to catch my all business exceptions at common place*

Just implement a custom JSF [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html).

---

> *and also it would be easy for me to check for the validation of session for each new request.*

This makes no sense. The container does it already by itself. I believe that you're concretely asking to check a session attribute representing the logged-in user. For that a servlet `Filter` is indeed the most sensible approach. Some may opt to use a JSF `PhaseListener` for that, but this is tight coupled to JSF requests and does not kick in on other requests.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your quick answer.

Comment: I just want to confirm few more things like implementing a custom ExceptionHandler should allow me to display business error message to particular page. It would be very helpful for me you can provide me an example of a custom JSF ExceptioHandler. Also, how can I redirect any request to an error page OR to a login page once the expired session is intercepted by Container itself?

Comment: The answer here is perfectly correct. Examples are easy to find if you search, for example:

http://javalabor.blogspot.se/2011/09/jsf-2-global-exception-handling.html

If you have further questions try searching. For sessions that are expired you see here (I searched your query for you)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992526/how-to-handle-session-expiration-in-jsf-2-0

Comment: Thanks Karl. Yes as usual @BalusC answers are always correct and precise.