# javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored

Tags: java, jsf, filter, viewexpiredexception, prettyfaces

i've created this webpage using jsf,prettyfaces and hibernate
i looked around and most people says that this error is because of cache
most of them found this error after login,logout and try to login back
but i found this error when i log in,and when i try to navigate to any other page,any link that i clicked will produce this error

what makes it harder is that this error doesnt occur everytime
sometimes when i try restart the server,login back,everythin work just fine
but sometimes when this error occur again, i tried restart the server and try login back.the same error still occur

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/ePortfolio.jsf - View /ePortfolio.jsf could not be restored.
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Pease check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)

Answer (score 1):

JSF keeps a (configurable) number of views in the session.  You will get this `ViewExpiredException` if you do a post to a view that cannot be restored anymore, ie. not present anymore in the list of views for that session.

There can be multiple reasons for this.  Two possible scenario's I can think of right now are:

- Session invalidated/expired
- Multiple (> configured number of sessions in view) views being created after the one that should be restored

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding this is caused by the combination of several things:

- A JSF-form containing an internal id for a field has been generated.
- The JSF-page has been changed, or the whole application redeployed, causing the internal ids to change.
- The JSF-form with the *old* internal id is submitted (a login page?) and the *old* internal id cannot be found in the *new* ids for the JSF-page.

You must have the page refreshed in the browser (getting the new id's) before attempting to submit again.