# How to create custom 404 messages in JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-3

Currently in my app when a user types some illegal destination in the URL bar, sees this:

[image]

I would like to make it more beautiful and customize it with my own markup and a bit of css.

-Do i need to program that on my app or i have to configure that in the application server?

-Where should i start from if i want to do that?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I will consider it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can declare custom `<error-page>`s in `web.xml` depending on `<error-code>` (the [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)) or `<exception-type>` (the full qualified exception class name which was been thrown, e.g. [`javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969)).

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

You've all freedom to fill in the markup in `404.xhtml`.