# Simple jsf2.0 application : javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException View could not be restored

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, viewexpiredexception

In a simple jsf2.0 application,I am getting this exception :javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException View could not be restored.

In console I am getting following error:
org.portletfaces.bridge.BridgeException: Must first call setPortletContext(PortletContext)

When I executed my application without useing Primefaces jar it worked properly. But after addind Primefaces jar I started getting this exception.

I am using Tomcat 7.2. 
EDIT: There are only 3 pages in the application and no backing bean.. A link on first page is invoking second page. But when I click on the link I am getting this error and the second page is not displayed.
Cant understand the cause of the problem. Please help.

Comment: If you're getting a ` ViewExpiredException` the view scoped backing bean has expired. Try refreshing the page.

Comment: Hi.. I have not yet created any baking bean. The application is so tiny that there are only 3 pages.. A link on first page is invoking second page. But when I click on the link I am getting this error and the second page is not getting displayed.

Comment: Show us the relevant code. Without the code we cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: @siebz0r: The exception is not necessarily related to having a view scoped backing bean. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *There are only 3 pages in the application and no backing bean.. A link on first page is invoking second page. But when I click on the link I am getting this error and the second page is not displayed.*

That can happen if you're navigating by `UICommand` links/buttons. You should not navigate by POST links/buttons at all, but just by GET links/buttons.

Replace all those [`UICommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) links/buttons which are incorrectly been used for page-to-page navigation by normal [`UIOutcomeTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutcomeTarget.html) links/buttons. In other words, replace `<h:commandButton>` by `<h:button>`, `<h:commandLink>` and `<p:commandLink>` by `<h:link>` and `<p:commandButton>` by `<p:button>`.

I.e. do not use

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Go to next page" action="nextpage" />
</h:form>
```

but instead use

```
<p:button value="Go to next page" outcome="nextpage" />
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)