# Why do I get Unexpected viewExpiredException when authenticated?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, websphere-7, webseal, ltpa

I'm working on an application using WAS 7.0 and Richfaces 3.3.3.

When I was working without authentication, I had only ViewExpiredException as expected, after a timeout.

Now that I'm going thru Webseal, with LTPA cookie, to the same machine, I get ViewExpiredException during my first or second Ajax Calls, making my application useless.

Would somebody have an idea why I suddenly get those ViewExpiredException's "all the time" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what Webseal is and what it is supposed to do, but the symptoms indicate that the HTTP session cookie isn't properly maintained anymore. Check/debug the HTTP traffic in your webbrowser's developer toolset. This cookie has the default name of `JSESSIONID`. For a background explanation how this is related to `ViewExpiredException`, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969

Comment: Thanks for your help. Webseal is in fact a reverse proxy. Looking in the http posts, there is a issue with the (absolute) URLS generated by my ajax calls. So I found this page : http://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/jsf-behind-reverse-proxy and I'm trying to use that custom ViewHandler... unsuccessfully until now.