# hibernate exception occured in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)

```
Sep 27, 2012 6:08:12 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase doPhase
SEVERE: JSF1054: (Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1, View ID: ) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@d0deb5]
Sep 27, 2012 6:08:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/qwerty] threw exception [viewId:/pages/welcome.jsf - View /pages/welcome.jsf could not be restored.] with root cause
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/pages/welcome.jsf - View /pages/welcome.jsf could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please write something of your problem too which caused above exception.

Comment: Let's see some code - and what does this have to do with Hibernate as nothng related to that is in the stacktrace

Comment: now i configur hibernate but after run..this type of output shows...

Comment: this is the first time i configure hibernate....let me tell the procedure to set the hibernate

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSF exception stating that the view and likely the HTTP Session has expired.  This may be because the query took a long time to perform.

- Either increase the session timeout
- Implement a looping AJAX poll on the page to keep the session alive
- Tune the query to perform more efficiently
- or do All of the Above