# Server page redirected to Filer before Login

Tags: web-applications, glassfish, java-ee-6

I have just deployed an Application which has a login page. Upon logging in with the "right" password and "username" however, the index.xhtml gets an error and gets ALWAYS redirected to the filter( a sessions time out) that has been configured. What are the reasons for the redirection? I made a check to see if the session was invalid, but no that was not the case. Here is the web.xml(part) where the filter has been set.

Error:

```
    javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.xhtml - Ansicht /index.xhtml konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden.
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
**********at **global.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:53)** --> in code snippet below*
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here the web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <!--
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
        -->
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <!-- settings for file upload -->
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>30</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
            <!-- sessionIDs are secure - look at:
                 http://www.java.net/node/703357 -->
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>global.SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/timeout.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page> 
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
        <location>/error.xhtml</location> 
    </error-page>
    -->
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
```

This is the filter code:

```
    public class SessionTimeoutFilter implements Filter {

        //private String timeoutPage = "timeout.xhtml";
        private String timeoutPage = "index.xhtml";


        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) 
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            if ((request instanceof HttpServletRequest) && (response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
                HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                // is session expire control required for this request?
                if (isSessionControlRequiredForThisResource(httpServletRequest)) {

                    // is session invalid?
                    if (isSessionInvalid(httpServletRequest)) {
                        String timeoutUrl = httpServletRequest.getContextPath() + "/" + getTimeoutPage();
                        //System.out.println("Session is invalid! redirecting to timeoutpage : "+timeoutUrl);

                        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(timeoutUrl);
                        return;

                    }
                }
            }
   **Line 53: ERROR here-->**         filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        private boolean isSessionControlRequiredForThisResource(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
            String requestPath = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
            boolean controlRequired = !StringUtils.contains(requestPath, getTimeoutPage());

            return controlRequired;
        }

        private boolean isSessionInvalid(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
            boolean sessionInValid = (httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId() != null) 
                    && !httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
            return sessionInValid;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }

        public String getTimeoutPage() {
            return timeoutPage;
        }

        public void setTimeoutPage(String timeoutPage) {
            this.timeoutPage = timeoutPage;
        }

    }
```

Please advise!

Comment: This problem is not caused by the filter at all. This problem is caused in the line as identified by the 1st line of the stacktrace. The filter just happens to have successfully passed in the call stack.

Comment: and why does my view expire?

Comment: You was likely submitting a page which was obtained from browser cache. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969 for in depth explanation and solutions.

Comment: Thanks Balus. Let me check them all and retry.

Comment: Firstly  I changed property javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD in web.xml to client. So now upon providing my username and password and on pressing command button "login" I am taken to the next page welcome.xhtml. However the credentials which I thought would be stored in session is all lost. I have IE browser. I followed the links you gave to disable caching dynamic JSF pages in IE by -->On the General tab, under Browsing History click Settings. Select the "Every time I visit the webpage" radio button. Inspite of it my user credentials arent't passed and hence I get a denied permission...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Try to change the url pattern that does not include the your login page or the index.xhtml.