# Glassfish Server Session invalidate

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, viewexpiredexception

I have deployed my web application on Glashfish 3.2.1.
I have set the session timeout to be 30 minutes in the web.xml.
My application has a login page and once this user is authenticated(password checked) the login proceeds loading the webpage. Although the user gets authenticated, the login button click only results in sessiona invalidate :(
I can see that the session details get lost. Why is this happening? Should I set something in my firefox browser? If no, how can I prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Please see my post here where I have mentioned the code:
[Server page redirected to Filer before Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315994/server-page-redirected-to-filer-before-login)

Comment: This question is not answerable without seeing some concrete code involving in the problem and details about the HTTP traffic (cookie headers, etc).

Comment: have updated my question..please take a look

Comment: You're not using JSP at all. You're using JSF/Facelets. You should not have used `[jsp]`, `[web-applications]`, `[java-ee-6]` tags, but just `[jsf]`, `[jsf-2]` and/or `[viewexpiredexception]` to attract the right folks. Your problem is basically answered in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969