# Reload page from backBean

Tags: jsf

How can I do to reload the JSF page after the session expire? 
I have a filter, when the session expires, it executes this code:

```
 res.sendRedirect("/index.xhtml");
```

But when I use a component when ajax, and the session is expired, nothing happens. So, think about taking a reload always after this line, but do not know how to do.

My idea is to put a line of reload when the session expires. Anyone know if it is possible to do this, or other better idea?

Answer (score 0):

See BalusC's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642969/1453701
Especially the following section: **Handling ViewExpiredException**