# ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored when user is logged in again

Tags: jsf, viewexpiredexception

My web app is built on spring boot + spring security + JSF 2.2.12

I have read a lot of posts about the view expired exception, and try to solve it using this [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored).

To be shortly, I have added **?faces-redirect=true** to my action methods, added NoCacheFilter to inform browser not cache the dynamic JSF pages. Also I have add expired.xhtml page. Also, I have added custom InvalidSessionStrategy implementation using this [sample](https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/5160269).

For the case, when I have two tabs in my browser, and perform log out in one tab, and in other I click `<p:commandButton` which trigger POST request for page navigation, everything works fine, browser redirect me to the login page.

But for case, when I have two tabs in my browser, and in one tab I perform log out and then log in, and in other I click again `<p:commandButton`, the ViewExpiredException is thrown.

Please, help me to solve this issue. Or tell me what I have missed?

Comment: When you logout, the entire HTTP session associated also gets destroyed (this is the definition of logout). When you login again and then click a command component like a `<p:commandButton>` in another tab (without refreshing the page which is backed by a view scoped bean), it will not find that view backed by that page in the current newly created HTTP session - Naturally, it has no knowledge of the previous HTTP session which was destroyed in its entirely, when you logged out.

Comment: What you missed is adding an error-handler for the exception, as per your linked question's very complete answer.

Comment: That's an **unavoidable** `ViewExpiredException`, in case that's not clear to you. It should end up in a (nice) error page. Was the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored) you found sufficiently helpful to cover that?

Comment: "That's an unavoidable ViewExpiredException" - yea, this was clear for me. I suppose, I have missed to add exception handler for ajax requests.

Comment: The exception handler help me. Thanks a lot.