# ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored when using aj4:poll

Tags: session, jsf, web.xml, ajax4jsf

I use a4j:poll to keep session alive but after some idle time i get "View could not be restored" error. I believe poll is creating views in background and after it reaches limit of 15(?) exception is thrown.

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="30000"/>
</h:form>
```

web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

BalusC said:
"So, it will only happen when you've manually set that limit way too low, or that you're continuously creating new views in background (e.g. by a badly implemented poll)."
in: [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)

and I believe it is my problem but i have no diea how to make it right :(

Comment: have you tried assigning an id to the form? perhaps the auto-generated id is  causing no views to increase

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this was the complete scenario that reproduces the problem?
In that case, the problem is your session-timeout that you have set to 1 second.
If that was not your case, edit your question.

Another problem that i have found is a a4j:poll inside a multipart form.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="30000"/>
</h:form>
```

Avoid this, It creates a new View ID on every poll request.

On each ajax request a View ID is returned, that is fine as long as the View ID is always the same. If you get a new View ID in each request, then there is a problem with the ajax request in your page.