# iframe not reading cookies in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cookies, cross-domain

**Chrome is not allowing a child iframe to read its own cookies.**

I have a parent webpage with a child iframe:

- parent at `https://first-site.com`
- child at `<iframe src="https://second-site.com">` (inside of parent)
- cookie set with

  - path: '/'
  - secure: true
  - httpOnly: false
  - domain: '.second-site.com'

I control both sites, and I want the iframe to perform an operation within the iframe that requires reading cookies for `.second-site.com`. The outer parent doesn't need to know anything about this.

**It works in all browsers except for Chrome.**

Chrome is simply not making the child page's own cookies available to the child.

Visiting the child page in its own window and performing the operation works in all browsers, including Chrome.

I've tried both of these options in all permutations:

- Set `secure:false` or `secure:true` for the cookie
- Set `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` for the iframe, or remove the `sandbox` attribute

What is Chrome doing differently, and how can an iframe in Chrome access its own cookies?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a relatively new cookie attribute called `SameSite` that was being set by my server automatically. Disabling this (while retaining the settings listed in the question) allows the iframe access to its own cookies in Chrome.

See also [Chrome feature status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4672634709082112) & [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07)

**UPDATE Aug 2020**

Chrome now blocks cookies without `SameSite` set, so you need to explicitly set it to `samesite=none` and `secure=true`.

Comment: How to disable SameSite attribute?

Comment: That's going to be specific to whatever server/framework you're using

Comment: Mandatory to set Secure flag too! (simply using HTTPS is not enough)

Comment: This solution no longer works with Chrome 84 release. Please advise.

Comment: @ChrisRuck Updated; now you have to explicitly set SameSite to "None"

Comment: Won’t work again with latest Chrome, setting Secure and SameSite=None with session_cookie_set_Paramus under PHP 7.3

Comment: I did the exact thing, and yet it is not preserving the session.

`<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />`
   
`<httpCookies sameSite="None" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />`

In my case, I'm not directly trying to access the cookie.  the iframe stores a var in session.  in subsequent clicks within the iframe, I need to use the session var stored.  However, it comes null when I do the ajax call within the first load of iframe too.

Comment: Can someone tell me if this still works / works again in 2021? My chrome-version is: 90.0.4430.93

Comment: I've set the SameSite attribute to none but the cookie is still not showing in my request headers. This is driving me nuts. Chrome version is 90.0.4430.212. 

Works fine if the page containing the iframe and the iframe content are on the same domain.

Comment: @h00ligan I added an answer, maybe this solution will suit you

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 106 (in 2022): document.cookie = 'name=value; ...; SameSite=None; Secure'; I use it in JS and Chrome&Edge omitted my cookie without this, when running in iframe on another domain.

Comment: still works this? my application is currently using http (http://myapp.coma.com). The iFrame url is https (https://web.zemb.com). But my app and iFrame url application are in different domains.  Can the iFrame still read the token from my app?  Need help
If I migrated my app to https, still not in same domains.  What can I do

Comment: there is coming update on Chrome during 2024 that makes it more complicated - https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd. the iframe website would need to add Partitioned; to their cookie or the user would need to allow the main website to host 3rd party cookies (when the iframe website isn't related to u, this could be a good workaround) - it seems this will break lots of websites that uses 3rd party add-ons which set their cookies (google analytics for example)

Answer (score 3):

The question was asked a long time ago, but it is still relevant.

I had the same problem and got a partial solution.

You can try **creating a proxy on your server** that will redirect requests to the target domain. This way, you will be able to **intercept cookies** from the response, **overwrite them** with the desired parameters, and **send them to the client**.

Example:

Your *index.html*

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src *; connect-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            const uuidv4 = () => ([1e7]+1e3+4e3+8e3+1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c => (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16));
            const id = localStorage.getItem('id') || uuidv4();
            localStorage.setItem('id', id);
            const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            iframe.setAttribute('height', '100%');
            iframe.setAttribute('src', `https://proxy.domain/?proxy_layer_id=${id}`);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You proxy server *index.php*

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$defaultTargetDomain = "target.domain";
$proxyDomain = "proxy.domain/";

$ck = $_COOKIE;
$userAgent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] ?? null;
$id = $_GET["proxy_layer_id"] ?? null;
$remoteDomain = $_GET["proxy_layer_domain"] ?? $defaultTargetDomain; // Use the default target domain if no other domain has been specified
$remotePath = $_GET["proxy_layer_path"] ?? null;
$sw = $_GET["proxy_layer_sw"] ?? false;

/* Decode remote domain */
if ($remoteDomain != null) {
    $remoteDomain = urldecode($remoteDomain);
}

/* Decode and parse remote path */
if ($remotePath != null) {
   $_url = parse_url($remotePath);
   $remotePath = $_url["path"]."?".($_url["query"] ?? "");
}

/* Generate service worker if requested */
if ($sw) {
    $sw = file_get_contents("./sw.js");
    $sw = str_replace("%id%", $id, $sw);
    $sw = str_replace("%target%", $remoteDomain, $sw);
    $sw = str_replace("%proxy%", $proxyDomain, $sw);
    header("Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8");
    print($sw);
    return;
}

function processCookies(&$cookies = []) {
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
        $values = trim(explode(":", $cookie)[1] ?? "");
        if (strlen($values) < 1) continue;
        $values = explode("; ", $values);
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            list($key, $value) = explode("=", urldecode($value));
            $ck[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

/* Generate final target URL */
$site = "https://" . $remoteDomain . $remotePath;

$request = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$ch = curl_init();

/* If there was a POST request, then forward that as well*/
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site . $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$headers = getallheaders();

/* Translate some headers to make the remote party think we actually browsing that site */
$extraHeaders = [];
if (isset($headers["Referer"])) {
    $extraHeaders[] = "Referer: " . str_replace($proxyDomain, $remoteDomain, $headers["Referer"]);
}
if (isset($headers["Origin"])) {
    $extraHeaders[] = "Origin: " . str_replace($proxyDomain, $remoteDomain, $headers["Origin"]);
}

/* Forward cookie as it came.  */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $extraHeaders);

$cookie = [];

foreach ($ck as $key => $value) {
    $cookie[] = "{$key}={$value}";
}

if (count($cookie)) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode("; ", $cookie));
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

curl_close($ch);

$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

$headerArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $headers);

$cookies = [];
$setCookies = [];

/* Process response headers */
foreach($headerArray as $header) {
    $skip = false;

    $colonPos = strpos($header, ":");

    if ($colonPos !== false) {
        $headerName = strtolower(substr($header, 0, $colonPos));

        /* Serialize html response */
        if (trim($headerName) == "content-type" && strpos($header, "text/html") !== false) {
            $query = http_build_query([
                "proxy_layer_id" => $id,
                "proxy_layer_domain" => $remoteDomain,
                "proxy_layer_sw" => true
            ]);

            /* Generate injection */
            $injection = file_get_contents("./injection.js");
            str_replace("%query%", $query, $injection);

            /* Add your own js to install the service worker */
            $body = str_replace("<head>", "<head><script>$injection</script>", $body);

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML($body);

            /* Get all hyperlinks */
            $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

            /* Proxy all target hyperlinks */
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
                $scheme = parse_url($href, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
                if (!$href || $href[0] === "#" || $scheme) continue;
                $prefix = $href[0] == "/" ? "" : "/";
                $path = $prefix . $href;
                $query = [
                    "proxy_layer_id" => $id,
                    "proxy_layer_domain" => $remoteDomain,
                    "proxy_layer_path" => $path
                ];
                $newLink = "https://" . $proxyDomain . "?" . http_build_query($query);
                $body = str_replace("\"$href\"", "\"$newLink\"", $body);
            }
        }

        /* Ignore content headers, let the webserver decide how to deal with the content */
        //if (trim($headerName) == "content-encoding") continue;
        //if (trim($headerName) == "content-length") continue;
        //if (trim($headerName) == "transfer-encoding") continue;
        //if (trim($headerName) == "location") continue;

        /* Ignore and get all cookie headers */
        if (trim($headerName) == "cookie") {
            $cookies[] = $header;
            $skip = true;
        }

        /* Change cookie domain for the proxy */
        if (trim($headerName) == 'set-cookie') {
            $header = str_replace('domain=' . $remoteDomain, 'domain=' . $proxyDomain, $header);
            $setCookies[] = $header;
            $skip = true;
        }
    }

    if ($skip) continue;

    header($header, false);
}

/* Merge all cookies */
processCookies($cookies);
processCookies($setCookies);

/* Set cookies */
foreach ($ck as $key => $value) {
    setcookie($key, $value, ["secure" => true, "samesite" => "None"]);
}

echo $body;
```

Your *sw.js*

```js
/**
This service worker intercepts all http requests and redirects them to the proxy server
*/

const id = '%id%';
const target = '%target%';
const proxy = '%proxy%';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
    self.skipWaiting();
    console.log('Installed', event);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    console.log('Activated', event);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    const url = decodeURI(event.request.url);
    if (!url.startsWith(location.origin) && !url.startsWith(`https://${proxy}`) && !url.startsWith(location.host) && (url.startsWith('http') || url.includes(target))) return; // Filter
    const [path, params] = (() => {
        if (url.startsWith('http')) {
            return url.split('/').slice(location.origin.split('/').length).join('/').split('?');
        } else {
            return url.split('?');
        }
    })();
    const request = new Request(encodeURI(`https://${proxy}?proxy_layer_id=${id}&proxy_layer_domain=${target}${typeof path === 'string' && path.length > 1 ? `&proxy_layer_path=/${path}` : ''}${typeof params === 'string' && params.length > 0 ? `&${params}` : ''}`), event.request);
    event.respondWith(new Promise((resolve, reject) => fetch(request).then(resolve).catch(e => {
        console.log("e", e);
        reject(e);
    })));
});
```

Your *injection.js*

```js
const serwiceWorkerPath = '/';
const query = '%query%';

navigator.serviceWorker.register(`${serviceWorkerPath}?${query}`).then(() => {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
}).then((reg) => {
    console.log('Service Worker is ready', reg);
    if (!localStorage.getItem('sw')) { // Reload if the service worker installed for the first time
        localStorage.setItem('sw', true);
        location.reload();
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

As a result, the contents of your iframe will have actual cookies in the `document.cookie`.

**PS:**
In my case, all endpoints were on different domains

Comment: Great! I wasn't too hard to adopt for my case and works perfectly. Thank you. Why was this downvoted?