# Iframe cannot access cookies created by itself

Tags: http, cookies, iframe

In my website (i.e. https://t.com) I have an iframe pointing to a website from another domain (i.e. https://a.com). This second website sets a cookie in my parent website when loading, but then it can´t read its own cookie.

So, my question is, how can I allow my second site, which is contained in the iframe, to access the cookie it has set when first loaded.

[image]

So, as you can see, when the content of the iframe is loaded, it sets a new cookie called **sid**.

[image]

But, when making a request within the iframe, that cookie is not being sent in the request headers.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094712/iframe-not-reading-cookies-in-chrome