# Google Chrome iFrame URL redirect issue

Tags: spring, google-chrome, iframe, wicket

we are not able to open URL in the iFrame when using chrome as a browser. We are using the latest version of chrome.

The Html we are using:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<body>
<h1>The iframe element</h1>
<iframe  src="http://localhost:8080/ui/overview" width="500px" height="500px">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

But the iframe is returning **Too many times redirect** issue.[image: too Many redirect Screenshot]

We have also used this in the **spring-security.xml** file:-

```
<headers>
        <frame-options disabled="true" />
    </headers>
```

We have also tried to configure in our Web application init() method:-

we set the wicket RenderStrategy to :- **RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.REDIRECT_TO_BUFFER**

When we inspect elements and see the network tab in chrome. This is the output. It shows **302 as Status**
:- [image: Redirect failed picture]

It is not working in google chrome only.
How can we solve this issue?

Please suggest some way to do it.

Comment: What happens if you try to load http://localhost:8080/ui/overview in a tab, i.e. not in IFrame ? Please take screenshots of the headers of two consecutive requests in Dev Tools. Comparing the headers between Google Chrome and Firefox should explain what is the difference between non-working and working setup.

Comment: Hello @martin-g, I'm teammate of kislay answering on his behalf - If we open localhost:8080/ui/overview in a tab, then website get open no issues at all. You can yourself try it out - https://data.smart360.me/smart360/ui/overview . Also, strange thing is it works in Firefox and worked in Google Chrome Jan 2020 release. From March 2020 release of Google Chrome, it stopped working. Will share the headers in question description, soon.

Comment: Maybe Chrome isn't sending cookies in your iframe? You could try disabling cookies in your web container and see whether it works with a session-identifier (JSESSIONID) in the url instead.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095345/497381