# calcom embed iframe html issue

Tags: node.js, next.js, cal

We're encountering an issue while integrating the appointment booking service calendar from our Calcom app into our website, either as an iframe or a pop-up window. Despite following the integration steps outlined in the documentation, we're facing difficulties as it's not functioning as expected, and we're observing errors in the console.

The Calcom app is self-hosted on AWS, and in its edition from two years ago, we added new functions such as creating interviews and generating tokens.

We've diligently checked the console for error messages, but unfortunately, we're struggling to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem. Interestingly, when attempting to use the same link in a new tab, it functions properly.

If anyone has experience with integrating the Calcom app into a website or has encountered similar issues before, we would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide.

This link look

http://localhost:3000/availability/185?next=/event-types/185&token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjo1LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im0tbWFobW91ZC1oYWt0aXYtY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJtLm1haG1vdWRAaGFrdGl2LmNvbSIsIm5hbWUiOiJIQUtUSVYiLCJyb2xlIjoiVVNFUiIsImlhdCI6MTcwOTgxNTk4Mn0.zCrv-womJ9W950l0dhnGyn9RVHt-tQOCTeK34eh1Nfs

Thank you in advance for your help[image]

Attempting to integrate the appointment booking service calendar from the Calcom app into the website.
Exploring two integration methods: embedding as an iframe or using a pop-up window.
Following the integration steps provided in the documentation.
Investigating the console for error messages to identify any issues.
Trying to access the same link in a new tab to observe its behavior.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively new cookie attribute called SameSite that was being set by my server automatically. Disabling this (while retaining the settings listed in the question) allows the iframe access to its own cookies in Chrome.

See also Chrome feature status & IETF draft

UPDATE Aug 2020

Chrome now blocks cookies without SameSite set, so you need to explicitly set it to samesite=none and secure=true.

[iframe not reading cookies in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094712/iframe-not-reading-cookies-in-chrome)