# How can I increase the display time of a View Expired error page?

Tags: html, jsf

I have implemented ViewExpiredException handling as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored) and [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) (Thank you @BalusC and team). It is working properly. However, the error page flashes by so quickly that the user is not informed that he/she has been redirected due to a session timeout. Is there a way to slow things down a bit?

Here is the error page:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Session Expired</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Session Expired</h1>
    <h3>You will be redirected to the starting page</h3>
    <p><a href="#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml">Click here if the redirect didn't work or if you are impatient.</a></p>
</body>
```

Comment: I would not expect it to disappear. Sure you don't have some http meta refresh or something in your error page?

Comment: Yes, I do (I added the error page to the question). Would it be better to wait for a user click>

Comment: You did not know/notice this before posting? Would have saved you the time creating the question since it is not jsf related at all (Would have saved me time too ;-)). And the same problem occurs if you use this a plain http server error page. Best solution is up to you. Add a several second delay or wait for a click

Comment: Sorry to have been incomplete, Kukeltje. Somehow I got it into my head that redirecting was the normal way to handle the timeout exception. I don't know how to add a delay - that is really what I was asking. I suppose I should have posted with an http or html tag

Comment: Uhhhh... then please learn what `content="0;` does... [mcve]... always... ;-)

Comment: Btw only use the jsf-2.3 tag for jsf specific issues. Tags are not for for what you use nut where the problem is

Comment: I'll be more diligent in the future.

Comment: Looks like you didn't read the text around the section where you copypasted this error page code example from .. The footnote already contained the answer.

Comment: I see it now. Sorry to have missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is exactly as you tell it to behave

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml" />
```

The `content="0` in there means: "Don't wait but redirect immediately". Changing the 0 to 10 will make it wait 10 seconds,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml" />
```

Effectively this is not jsf related at all but plain html. Same would have been a problem with a normal 404 error page