# Program crashes if I make some repeated actions

Tags: jsf, view, state

I created a simple crud jsf project.My page contains dataTable and it is filled up form database.Sometimes, My program does not running especially after 3 or 4 requests.For example , I caught up a scenariao like this: Whenever I trigger my selectOneMenu multiple times(Example: 13-14 times) I saw DevTools console screen gives error

```
<p:selectOneMenu id=studentNo"
    value="#{myBean.studentNo}" style="width:150px">
        <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.onStudentChange}"  
            update=":formTabInvoiceList:tabViewInvoiceList:StudensList:table-wrapper"/>

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose student number" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems  value="#{myBean.studentNumbersList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Error is :

```
 <partial-response>
   <error>
     <error-name>
        javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
     </error-name>
     <error-message>
        /xhtml/pages/Invoice.xhtmlNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: 
        /xhtml/pages/Invoice.xhtml
     </error-message>
  </error>
</partial-response>
```

I found this error on network tab of DevTools.I caught this error another repeated scenarios on my program.

I googled it and I found some solutions but I did not solve  it.
My web.xml file contains

```
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
```

.

Also I check all components on my xhtml file to find components that have same id.All components have different id.

My primeFace version is : 3.4.1

myFaces : 2.1.10

Do you have any idea?

my web.xml file is :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)

Comment: No.I have tried everything but I still get error.

Comment: Are you sure you are using JSP and not facelets?

Comment: I use facelets @Kukeltje

Comment: It is a JSF  project and I use facelets

Comment: Then why did you add jsp as a tag? And what if you, in your not posted [mcve] just use plain jsf tags with ajax? Same problem? Then the Q is not PrimeFaces related. Narrow things down, debug, simplify...

Comment: I edited my question.I will try plan jsf tags with ajax.Thank you very much

Comment: I used plain jsf tags with ajax same problem is still continue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212435/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-hagi10).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding these lines.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION</param-name>
  <param-value>40</param-value>
</context-param>
```