# Getting view javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException in jemeter5.3

Tags: jmeter, jsf-2.2

Trying to test JSF2.2 application in jmeter5.3. Getting javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
in each request. Using Regular expression extractor to read view state[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vbZj.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642969/2897748)

> The ViewExpiredException will be thrown whenever the javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is set to server (default) and the enduser sends a HTTP POST request on a view via <h:form> with <h:commandLink>, <h:commandButton> or <f:ajax>, while the associated view state **isn't available in the session anymore**.

So you're sending stale viewstate parameter, check [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual entry, you need to extract the ViewState not only once, but from **each and every subsequent page** so if you placed Regular Expression Extractor as a child of a single request try moving it one level up

Few more hints:

- [Using regular expressions for extracting data from HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), I would suggest considering switching to [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) instead
- [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page