# javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException seemingly ignored

Tags: java, jsf, viewexpiredexception

I've put the following into my web.xml:

```
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/expiredIndex.jsf</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsf</location>
</error-page>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

When I start my app, and wait for 1 minute, if I then attempt to interact with it (JSF 1.2, `h:commandButton`) I get the error

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone tell me why it is the `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException` is not being picked up?  I'm looking for the most basic expiry setup possible and surely that's all that is necessary in the web descriptor.

Thanks

*EDIT*

I now have in my web.xml the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Error</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myClient.ErrorFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Error</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.servlet.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/expiredIndex.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
```

(these entries are the last filter entries in the web.xml) and a new filter with the doFilter method as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206922/issue-with-jsf-viewexpiredexception-and-multiple-error-page-tag-definitions-in-we) post.  What should be happening now is the `rootCause` should unwrap the ViewExpiredException which should thus redirect the user to my `expiredIndex` page when the servlet session times out.  Instead I get a 500.  I can't see what else to I need to do the correct redirect in this situation.  Help!

*EDIT 2*

Error from the 500 is:

```
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:185)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:103)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    prismClient.ErrorFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
```

which I guess is the standard one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `ViewExpiredException` -as every other `FacesException`- is under the covers been wrapped in a `ServletException`. This one is been used to find matches in the declared error pages. The closest match is `java.lang.Throwable` and thus the associated error page is been shown.

If no match would have been found, then the root cause of the `ServletException` would have been unwrapped and a second pass through the declared error pages will be made with the unwrapped exception. If you remove the `java.lang.Throwable` entry, you'll see that this will work.

If you want to keep the `java.lang.Throwable`, then best what you can do is to create a `Filter` which unwraps any `FacesException` from the `ServletException` and rethrows it.

#### See also:

- [Issue with JSF `ViewExpiredException` and multiple error page definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206922/issue-with-jsf-viewexpiredexception-and-multiple-error-page-tag-definitions-in-we)

Comment: Interesting - I see the expiredIndex page is correctly setup, but I'm not handling the underlying java exception in the back end.  Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my question as I have another point to ask about. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: One thought relevant here possibly - should I not explicitly cast the rootCause throw as a ViewExpiredException instead of a RuntimeException in order to lock it down or is that not a good idea?

Comment: That's not necessary. Casting just changes the runtime type, but not the actual type. The comparisons on the declared error pages happens against the actual type (using `instanceof` under the waters and so on). Unless you wouldn't like to rethrow all other `RuntimeExceptions` plain. As per your new problem, what exactly is the 500 you got? The default error page for `java.lang.Throwable`? If not, what is the trace?

Comment: Ah I see it, the full qualified name of the `ViewExpiredException` in `<exception-type>` is incorrect. It should be `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException` as in your initial declaration and not `javax.servlet.ViewExpiredException` as in your updated declaration. The wrong one does not exist at all.

Comment: @BalusC well spotted! This is my first stab at filters and your help is very appreciated indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the blog posted on similar issue [here](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=164):  it's less cumbersome and quite effective. Be sure to include your "view-handler" tags within the "application" tags, doing this worked for me, cheers.

Comment: Blog posts can change as they are outside of the control of Stack Overflow. Please consider writing a summary of the blog's approach, so your comment will be useful even if the blog moves or disappears in the future.

Comment: Multiple sources are a good idea too. If the blog has changed, you can have a professional backup source