# Hide/handle servlet exception stack trace output

Tags: java, servlets, stack-trace, servlet-filters

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716030/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-seemingly-ignored) post I have thought of another question I cannot seem to find the answer to on the interweb.

I have a servlet filter which detects session timeouts and redirects to an error page.  Due to my fledgling java I've used try catch blocks to catch exceptions and handle them gracefully, but in a session timeout situation, the context is invalid so I don't think I've got any code I can do that with which will stop the 'viewId could not be restored' stace trace appearing in my log even though I have a filter handling it.

How can I stop the exception trace from appearing in my log?  It will be monitored autoamtically in live and it will be a false positive call out to the support team for this sort of error.

Any help appreciated.

*EDIT*

To be more clear, my code clip is currently

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        logger.error("Caught Servlet Exception");
        Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
        logger.error("Root cause is " + rootCause.toString());

        if (rootCause instanceof RuntimeException) { // This is true for any FacesException.
            logger.error("Rethrowing exception as RuntimeException" + rootCause.toString());
            throw (RuntimeException) rootCause; // Throw wrapped RuntimeException instead of ServletException.
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

The log says:

```
    |STDOUT| 2011-01-19 10:40:57,803 | ERROR | [http-8080-5]: Exception in the filter chain
    javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
<snip>
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
<snip>
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
        ... 21 more
    19-Jan-2011 10:40:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:185)
<snip>
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    |STDOUT| 2011-01-19 10:40:57,803 | ERROR | [http-8080-5]: Caught Servlet Exception
    |STDOUT| 2011-01-19 10:40:57,803 | ERROR | [http-8080-5]: Root cause is javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
    |STDOUT| 2011-01-19 10:40:57,803 | ERROR | [http-8080-5]: Rethrowing exception as RuntimeExceptionjavax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/index.jsf - View /index.jsf could not be restored.
```

As you can see from the code, I've caught the servlet exception in the filter, but the stack is still appearing in the log.

*NEXT EDIT*
The complete list of filters in my web.xml is as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Error</filter-name>
    <filter-class>prismClient.ErrorFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Error</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4):

Filters are executed in the order they are defined in the `web.xml` file. In your case, it looks like the jfaces filter is executed first and logging the stack trace before your custom filter has a chance to filter it out. Try making your filter entry in `web.xml` the first one.

**EDIT**

It's possible that some other filter in the chain is logging the `ServletException` before it throws it. In the stack trace you posted, it looks like there is a filter for `ajax4jsf` that may be logging the `ServletException`.  Do you have the source for this?  How may filters are in your `web.xml`?

**EDIT 2**

It looks like ajax4jsf is catching `ServletException` and logging an error message before throwing it back out.  I suggest you get the source for the version of ajax4jsf that you're using and look at the lines in the stack trace (`BaseXMLFilter.java` line 178 and `BaseFilter.java` line 290) and search for logging statements.  If you find them, you can either remove them from the source and rebuild ajax4jsf, or disable the category in your logging configuration file.  I don't recommend the latter, because you will miss other errors that may occur in the filter.

If that is not the source of the error message, then I'm afraid I've run out of ideas.

Comment: But unfortunately not working.  I put the filter entries (`filter` and `filter-mapping`) before the RichFaces Filter and I still get a stacktrace in the log when the session timesout.  I use Log4J in a really standard way.

Comment: Jason many thanks for your persistence.  I've edited my post to include the full, ordered list of my filters.  I see the al4sf filter you mentioned, but I'm under the impression I have to have it in there.  Configuration on the other hand is a different kettle of fish - this one I believe is defined as recommended in richfaces setup documentation - do feel free to suggest how you see it would be better configured based on my OP.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you rethrow the exception, whatever is logging it is still getting it.  Even though you're blocking the ServletException out and rethrowing the RunTimeException (which ViewExpiredException is), something higher in the filter chain may be rewrapping it.

Do any of the logs you write in this method also show up in the log before the stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for your words.  In answer to your question, no - the stack trace is always first out.

Comment: Then my conjecture about the rethrow being the problem must be wrong.  Unfortunately I've got no further ideas at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try writing a Session filter yourself? Find a nice example [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/http-session-handling-tutorial-using-servlet-filters-session-error-filter-servlet-filter.html).

Comment: I did write the filter myself. Your example is essentially what I've already written (except I haven't limited mine to the http protocol). I've edited my post to be more specific.

Comment: you don't handle the ViewExpiredException there.

Comment: No but I handle it as a RunTimeException which is what it is.

Comment: yeah, I see that, but you just throw it again! And it's not instanceof RuntimeException, it's a subclass of RuntimeException.

Comment: @Elijah: an instance of a subclass of RuntimeException _is_ an instanceof RuntimeException.

Comment: My point was that he doesn't handle it specifically. It's like catching an Exception and throwing it again: this way you wouldn't really be able so see what sort of problem you just had.